# Prove that $\Bbb{R}$ is infinite union of closed sets.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $I_{n}=\{x\in \Bbb{R}: -n\leq x\leq n; n\in \Bbb{N}\}$. Then $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_{n}=\mathbb{R}$.
Take a sequence $\{x_n\}\in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty{[-n,n]}$ then $\{x_n\}$ converges a point $x\in [-n,n]$ then clearly $x\in \Bbb{R}$. Therefore $\{x_n\}\in \Bbb{R}$ for all but finitely many $n$. Which implies that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty[-n,n]\subset\Bbb{R}$. Similarly the opposite inclusion.

Am I on right track? Thanks!

Comment: @Subhajit: edited.

Comment: How do you prove that $I_n=[-n,n]$? What is $I_n$ anyhow$?

Comment: Why don't yoy just take $\mathbb R=\mathbb R\cup\mathbb R\cup\mathbb R\cup\cdots$? do the closed sets have to be distinct?

Answer (score 1):

Why so complicated? Pick arbitrary real $x$. By the Archimedian Property, $\exists n \in \mathbb N : n > |x|$. So $x \in [-n,n] \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} [-i,i]$

Comment: Is my first inclusion correct?

Comment: Yes, it is. But this is a simpler approach

Comment: for opposite inclusion can i use sequential approach.

Comment: You can pick a sequence in $\mathbb R$ and then show that all the elements of the sequence belong to the union, while it will take some work, I havent got the perfect idea yet.

Comment: Whenever, you wanna show, $A⊂B$, you have to consider all elements of $A$, so, it's meaningless, to show this inclusion by sequence, as we all know sequence is countable, but given set is uncountable.

Comment: Yes, that's why I don't approve of the sequential approach, especially the other implication

Comment: @Joseph  why do you try so, is there any particular reason?

Comment: It's done. Thanks!

Comment: I'd say "$n>|x|$".

Comment: Yes, thats more concrete. I will edit that

Answer (score 1):

As , all $I_n$ are subsets of $\mathbb{R} $, so, there union must be subset of $\mathbb{R} $

From , other side, take any $x\in \mathbb{R} $, then just creat the interval $[-\lceil |x| \rceil, \lceil |x| \rceil]$ , and clearly it's in the form of $[-n,n]$ , for some $n$.

So, the equality.